# How do i send a VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK in C#?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I found many things googling, but none I could actually use, so I'm just searching for a simple method, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of the problem is that you must PInvoke into native code in order to use these methods.  PInvoke is a pretty big topic and I suggest reading up on it a bit.

Luckily though most things which can be PInvoke'd at this point have samples available on the web.  For instance, take a look at the following article on CodeIdol.  It gives a full winforms sample on how to use this key and many others in a c# application.

http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharpckbk2/Delegates,-Events,-and-Anonymous-Methods/Using-the-Windows-Keyboard-Hook/

Comment: Your link is about hooking into the input chain to be notified about input, he wants to send input.

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 0):

JardPar is correct, you will have to PInvoke to send the `VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK` key. You can use the `user32.SendInput` function to achieve this. Take a look at [pinvoke.net: SendInput (user32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput).

Answer (score 0):

I've had better luck with [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx) in the past. The method definition should look like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte vkCode, byte scanCode, int flags, IntPtr extraInfo);
```